# MySQLi prepared statements are silentely mangling my data. Is this expected behaviour?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My code currently uses `mysqli::query` and checks `mysqli::$warning_count`. When trying to insert text into an integer column, `0` gets inserted and a warning is generated. However, I'm just starting to learn prepared statements and for the same query, no warning is generated.

**Here's an excerpt from my code:**

```
$db_err_msg = 'Database Error: Failed to update profile';
$sql = "UPDATE tblProfiles SET intBookId = ? WHERE lngProfileId = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) or output_error($db_err_msg);

$book = 'CA';
$id = 10773;
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $book, $id) or output_error($db_err_msg);
$stmt->execute() or output_error($db_err_msg);
echo '$stmt->affected_rows is ', $stmt->affected_rows, "\n";

if ($mysqli->warning_count) {
    $warnings = $stmt->get_warnings();
    do {
        trigger_error('Database Warning (' . $warnings->errno . '): '
            . $warnings->message, E_USER_WARNING);
    } while ( $warnings->next() );
}
else {
    echo 'no warnings', "\n";
}
```

**which produces the following output:**

> $stmt->affected_rows is 1
>   no warnings

Note that the `intBookId` column has a `TINYINT` data type. The same query generates a warning when using `mysqli::query`, but not when using prepared statements.

Enabling strict mode does not help. It will turn the warning into an error when using `mysqli::query`, but when using prepared statements the column is silently updated with a `0`;

For the record, my application already does extensive validation before it gets to this point. But I wanted this extra validation as way to catch anything I might miss by mistake.

**Note:** It's beyond the scope of the current project to switch to PDO.

**Why is this happening with MySQLi prepared statements? Is this expected behaviour?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it may not be immediately obvious, it is expected behaviour.

**Because of this line of code:**

```
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $book, $id) or output_error($db_err_msg);
```

PHP is casting the value to an integer before sending it to MySQL. MySQL receives the value `0` which is a valid value for the column and no warning is generated.

**If you don't want PHP to do this, then you need to send it as a string. Like so:**

```
$stmt->bind_param('si', $book, $id) or output_error($db_err_msg);
```

MySQL will receive the string 'CA' and generate a warning about it being an incorrect integer value.

**Note:** By sending everything as a string, MySQL will have to do a little more processing to convert the strings to integers, but it was already doing that anyway when the whole query was sent as a string using mysqli::query.

**Note:** A related problem occurs when using integers that are greater than `PHP_INT_MAX`. If you think an integer value will surpass that maximum (which is platform-dependent and only 2147483647 on 32-bit platforms) and precision is important, it's safer to send it as a string.